# Group gcov coverage results per folder

Tags: code-coverage, gcov

I'm wondering if there is any way to get `gcov` coverage results while keeping the source code tree structure, so that we can see coverage results for entire folders ?
I'm currently using `lcov` to visualize the results, but I don't mind switching to another tool if is provides that features.

Lcov output (top view)

```
src/folder1/subfolder1/  12%
src/folder1/subfolder2/  39%
src/folder2/subfolder1/  76%
src/folder2/subfolder2/  100%
```

What I'm looking for

```
src/  58%
|-  folder1/ 22%
|     |- subfolder1  12%
|      - subfolder2  39% 
 -  folder2/ 94%
      |- subfolder1  76%
       - subfolder2  100%
```

I'm working on a large codebase, and I'd like to have a quick overview of which parts of the code are well covered or not. It would be even better if I could expand the subfolders so that I can see only up to a certain depth :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to generate Html-report based on gcov/lcov results. It can help you to visualize results and sorts them differently.

For example

lcov --capture --rc lcov_branch_coverage=1 --directory . lcovrc --output coverage.info
genhtml --branch-coverage --output ./report_dir/ coverage.info

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how does that help with my problem ?

Comment: in html report, you should see coverage not only for a file but for subdir

Comment: Well as I mentioned above, it generates coverage for the files directly under the folder, and not recursively :/

Comment: I'm not sure that I see anything about recursive above. But I guess this is your responsibility to gather coverage recursively. It is needed to compile and then run your application to gather coverage data. As a result, coverage will reflect this.